# get data from another class to vf page

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I have a class which is using object of another class and I want to use it in my vf page .`This is my Vf page and I want to access my CalculatorView class data in my vf page. ``

```
public with sharing class PaymentPlanController {
CalculatorView calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency{get;set;}

}

    public class CalculatroView {
        public String everyDay{get; set;}
    }


<apex:page standardController="Loan_Payment_Plan__c" extensions="PaymentPlanController,CalculatorView" sideBar="false"
           docType="html-5.0">` 
  <apex:selectRadio value="{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency}">
     <selectOption itemValue="{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency.everyDay}" 
                   itemLabel="{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency.everyDay}"/>
  </apex:selectRadio>
```

Can someone tell me how can i get the data everyday from my calculatorview class to the vf page? thanks

Comment: If you add `public` to the `calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency` declaration then `{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency.everyDay}` should work. Though I don't understand what you are trying to do with that value in your apex tags.